# JPA find by date between two dates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

here I'm trying to use JPA fetch the data from MYSQL DB, but I'm facing trouble to set data object to handle the condition, as I understand I have to create and data object to handle it,how do i creat date object to handle the needed

here my normal query :

```
select t.id, t.MSISDN, t.Param1, t.param2
  from BULK_REPOSITORY t
where t.Camp_Start_Date between Sysdate - 2 and sysdate
   and t.status = 0
   and t.camp_type = 1;
```

application :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    Bulk_repository bulk ;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(Bulk_repositoryRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

            // fetch customers by Status
            log.info("Customer found with findByStatus('0'):");
            log.info("--------------------------------------------");
            repository.findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStart_dateBetween(1,2,Date,Date-2).forEach(on -> {
                log.info(on.toString());
            });
        };
    }
```

Bulk_repository class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BULK_REPOSITORY")
public class Bulk_repository {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "msisdn")
   private String msisdn;

   @Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
   private Date campStartDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_end_date")
   private Date campEndDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_type")
   private int campType;

   @Column(name = "camp_cd")
   private String camp_cd;

   @Column(name = "status")
   private int status;

   @Column(name = "process_date")
   private Date processDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_date")
   private Date entryDate;

   @Column(name = "entry_user")
   private String entry_user;

   @Column(name = "param1")
   private String param1;

   @Column(name = "param2")
   private String param2;

   @Column(name = "param3")
   private String param3;

   @Column(name = "param4")
   private String param4;

   @Column(name = "param5")
   private String param5;

   @Column(name = "error_desc")
   private String error_desc;

   @Column(name = "fulfilment_status")
   private int fulfilment_status;
## getter and setter and ToString
```

Bulk_repositoryRepository class :

```
  import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {
          List<Bulk_repository>  findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStart_dateBetween(int status, int campType,Date campStart_dateStart, Date campStart_dateEnd);
         Bulk_repository findById(long id);
    }
```

Comment: since you have changed the column your method name in the repository will change to 

**findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateBetween**

Comment: also, let us know what **date* do you want to pass as date

Comment: just trying to pass the date as below where t.Camp_Start_Date between Sysdate - 2 and sysdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have changed the method, as I suggested in comments

change method **demo** in **AccessingDataJpaApplication**  as below

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(Bulk_repositoryRepository repository) {
return (args) -> {          

    Date currentDate = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);

    Date dateTwoDaysAgo = cal.getTime();


        // fetch customers by Status
        log.info("Customer found with findByStatus('0'):");
        log.info("--------------------------------------------");
        repository. findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateBetween(1,2,currentDate,dateTwoDaysAgo).forEach(on -> {
            log.info(on.toString());
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: corrected method name to findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateBetween

Comment: thank you dear , its worked fine , but my date format in my table like 2019-10-23

Comment: well:), it's just beginning about date, timezones would be next for you , date is stored as number in database, the format you see is just a local representation, all you need to ensure you keep datatype in a database as Date/timestamp  subsequently you can improvise, I always keep a date in UTC timezone

Comment: please have look for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540806/spring-jpa-with-http-request-api

Answer (score 1):

you method is right you just misspelled CampStartDate;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {
      List<Bulk_repository>  findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartdateBetween(int status, int campType,Date campStart_dateStart, Date campStart_dateEnd);
     Bulk_repository findById(long id);
}
```

Comment: yah but im calling into my main class but i dont where can i create the object date