# findby date between 2 dates

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

here im trying to find the data where the date between `campStartDate` and `campEndDate` but i can't set static date i just looking to get the date between campStartDate and camEndDate

i have tried this but i don't know how to get the data in correct way :

```
public class Bulk_repository {
@Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "camp_start_date")   
   private Date campStartDate;

   @Column(name = "camp_end_date")
   private Date campEndDate;
}
```

CrudRepository class :

```
public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {

List<Bulk_repository>findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateLessThanEqualAndCampEndDateGreaterThanEqual(int status, int campType,Date campStartDate,Date campEndDate);
Bulk_repository findById(long id);
}
```

application :

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(Bulk_repositoryRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {          
    log.info("--------------------------------------------");
         repository.findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateLessThanEqualAndCampEndDateGreaterThanEqual(0,2,currentDate,currentDate).forEach(on -> {
                log.info(on.toString());
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell us what is the problem, what error are you facing.

Comment: i just want to get the data where where date between two dates , i have 2 col campStartDate and campEndDate , just looking to get the data where date between my condation .

Comment: Yep, and what's wrong with your code? What's going wrong with that attempt?

Comment: i have no problem with code but my problem is i dont want to set currentDate , i just need it should'nt provide by me , it must be taken from database , see my application class

Comment: any problem using between, refer to your thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58519147/jpa-find-by-date-between-two-dates

Comment: its different case i was looking to get the data where date between sysdate and sysdate -2 , but here its different senario i just want to get the data where date between two col campStartDate and campEndDate

Comment: you mean data for a date which is between camp start date and camp end date

Comment: campStartDate < arugument < campEndDate right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering **campStartDate** will always be less than **campEndDate**, and if you are trying to find records for a date which you pass a date which is falling in between, than I think you got your comparison wrong, you should change condition as below

```
public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {

List<Bulk_repository>findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateGreaterThanEqualAndCampEndDateLessThanEqual(int status, int campType,Date campStartDate,Date campEndDate);
Bulk_repository findById(long id);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you don't want to pass date then JPQL can help you, try changing method signature in repository something like

```
public interface Bulk_repositoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Bulk_repository, Long> {

@Query("SELECT b FROM Bulk_repository b WHERE b.status = :status and b.campStartDate >=CURRENT_DATE and b.campEndDate <= CURRENT_DATE)
List<Bulk_repository>findAllByStatusAndCampTypeAndCampStartDateGreaterThanEqualAndCampEndDateLessThanEqual(@Param("status") int status);
Bulk_repository findById(long id);

}
```

Comment: thank you dear, but the point on application class i don't want to set static date just only getting the data where the data between campStartDate and campEndDate  from my table , sorry for my english

Comment: Can you write sql for same, you need to pass at least one date,probably a jpql can help you

Comment: @yongshi also try jpql approach, it doesn't require to pass a date